# Create directory in web deploy package?

Tags: asp.net, webdeploy

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application which I would like to publish to a Web Deploy package and deploy using the deploy.cmd script generated as part of the Web Deploy package. This basically works fine but I have one problem.

My application generates image files which are stored in a temporary directory as part of the web site (basically a subdirectory of the IIS site's physical location called temp). However, whenever I deploy my site using the deploy.cmd script, this directoty is deleted. Instead, I would like the deploy script to make sure the directory is present and that the IIS user has access to it. Is this possible to do with Web Deploy out of the box?